# Java RXTX and Import Issues on Ubuntu

Tags: java, serial-port, netbeans-7, rxtx

I have run the following to install the RXTX libraries in Ubuntu x86 13.04.

## sudo apt-get install librxtx-java

I am using Netbeans and have added the RXTXComm.jar as a library to my application.

The code still flags the error of not being able to import the following:

```
import gnu.io.CommPort;
import gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier;
import gnu.io.SerialPort;
```

librxtxSerial.so  is in these locations:

```
/usr/lib/jni/librxtxSerial.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/i386/librxtxSerial.so
```

I have added a file to /etc/ld.so.conf.d/rxtx.conf which contains the line:

```
/usr/lib/jni/
```

I then ran sudo ldconfig.

I continue to get the java import issues in netbeans ? Any ideas?

Comment: What "issues"? Are you getting an error message? What does it say?

Comment: Sure it can not see the gnu.io library and as such its flagging the import gnu.io commands.

Comment: import gnu.io.CommPort;
  symbol:   class CommPort
  location: package gnu.io

Comment: And you've imported `RXTXcomm.jar` into your Java project?

Comment: Yes RXTXcomm.jar is imported to the project.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe PureJavaComm is better library - it doesn't use native libraries.